# How to insert other values into database in Visual Studio when there is an ID auto incremented

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio

`Userid` is auto incremented value and giving default as its value doesn't work

```
string inse = @"insert into registration (userid, firstname, lastname, day, 
                                          month, year, address, city, pincode, 
                                          state, country, phoneno, emailaddress) 
                values  (DEFAULT, @firstname, @lastname, @day, 
                         @month, @year, @address, @city, @pincode,
                         @state, @country, @phoneno, @emailaddress)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(inse, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txtfname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtlname.Text);
..
```

etc

Comment: If the value it auto-incremented, then you shouldn't pass it as long as the database is doing the incrementing

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Symon makes a good point for normal application operation but if you're bulk-loading initial data into a new database, specifying the value is a valid action. SQL Server has `IDENTITY_INSERT` but that won't help if you're using something else.

Comment: Also, once we know which RDBMS you're using, this probably can be marked as a duplicate. It's just a matter of figuring out which one.

Comment: It works now . Thanks @symon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't add it at all in the query, if it's auto-incremented then the database will handle the ID.

Query that should work:

```
string inse = @"insert into registration(firstname,lastname,day,month,year,
               address,city,pincode,state,country,phoneno,emailaddress) 
               values  
               (@firstname,@lastname,@day,@month,@year,@address,@city,@pincode,
               @state,@country,@phoneno,@emailaddress)";
```